# xtrabackup only performs a full back up if is executed with super user privileges

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

According to this [link](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/xtrabackup_bin/creating_a_backup.html), I executed this command to backup my database:

```
 xtrabackup --backup --databases='database' --target-dir=/home/user/backups --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
```

But I get the following error:

```
160520 02:00:54  version_check Done.
160520 02:00:54 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: root, password: set, port: 0, socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Using server version 5.5.44-MariaDB
xtrabackup version 2.4.2 based on MySQL server 5.7.11 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 8e86a84)
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: cd to /var/lib/mysql/
xtrabackup: open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
xtrabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = .
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = .
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_file_size = 5242880
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
```

I solved it by running the same command with sudo, the problem is that the backup directory gets created as root so my user doesn't have access to that directory so I always have to change the ownership recursively for that directory so I can be able to read it. This method isn't pretty efficient to me.

- Is there any other alternative to do this?
- Do I always have to
  execute this command with sudo?

Comment: Have you tried running it with the same user that owns the database files? Usually that's `mysql`.

Comment: What I want to do is run it with MY user.

Comment: What you want and what UNIX privileges allow might be two different things. The database is supposed to be protected.

Comment: @tadman so what do you recommend?

Comment: Don't fight the permission system and work with it. Get the `mysql` user to do the backup work for you and dump it in a directory you have access to. This is easy to do with `cron`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xtrabackup` tool runs as the user invoking it and that user must be able to read the database files which are normally owned by **mysql:mysql** and mode 660.

An easy fix is usually to add the user to the mysql group, for example:

```
useradd -G mysql yves
```

Then logout and re-open the session, it should work.

Comment: Sorry even though I made the user be part of mysql group I still get the same error. But seems like the one that doesn't have write permissions is mysqld `InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.`

Comment: Make sure that all files in /var/lib/mysql have group read/write privs and then your user should be able to take a backup. innobackup operates at the file level so if your user can't open the files, then innobackup (as executed by you) cannot either. Or write a wrapper script that takes the backup as root then chown's the completed backup; super simple.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also needed to allow listing of database directories for users in the `mysql` group: `find /var/lib/mysql/* -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error after successfully running the backup script for some time and can't figure out what changed look for a new folder under your MySQL directory (usually /var/lib/mysql).  I've twice found new DBs created with permissions only at the user level (ie: drwx------) with no group read access.  A quick chmod 750 of the directory to fix permissions takes care of it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to fight the way Percona wants you to use their stuff, though I could be wrong.

I know that innobackupex (perl script installed with xtrabackup) is supposed to be run as root, since one of Percona's support engineers says so here: https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtrabackup/8748-error-trying-to-run-backup

Maybe the xtrabackup command is just supposed to be used the same way?